# Custom compound view throws "Error inflating class"

Tags: java, android, view

I have made a custom compound view:

linkui.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some Text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and put it in an activity.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!-- ....Other components -->

    <com.button.LinkUI
        android:id="@+id/link"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the java class for the view, which has a setter `setText` :

```
public class LinkUI extends LinearLayout {

    private TextView textView;

    public LinkUI(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public LinkUI(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context,attrs);
        init();
    }
    public LinkUI(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public void setText(String str){
        this.textView.setText(str);
    }

    private void init() {
        inflate(getContext(),R.layout.linkui,this); <---
        this.textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);    

    }

}
```

According to the debug console, the view starts with the second constructor `public LinkUI(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)`, then  crashes at `init()` when the view inflates the layout `R.layout.linkui`, can anyone tell me what's wrong with inflating the xml?

Error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.site, PID: 13060
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #63: Error inflating class com.button.LinkUI
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at com.mikepenz.fastadapter.items.AbstractItem.getViewHolder(AbstractItem.java:233)
    at com.mikepenz.fastadapter.FastAdapter$OnCreateViewHolderListenerImpl.onPreCreateViewHolder(FastAdapter.java:1628)
    at com.mikepenz.fastadapter.FastAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(FastAdapter.java:382)
    at com.mikepenz.fastadapter.AbstractAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(AbstractAdapter.java:128)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6073)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5243)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5153)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2061)
    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:562)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1408)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:580)
    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:170)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3374)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2901)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16772)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5139)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16772)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5139)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:703)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:770)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16772)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1662)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16772)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5139)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16772)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5139)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16772)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5139)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16772)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5139)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16772)
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1081)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16772)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5139)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
  at android.support.v7.widg
```

My sdk version:

compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

Comment: Find the first line in the stacktrace which references a class and method which you created. What line of code does it refer to?

Answer (score 2):

Don't call initUi() in the constructor, call it in onFinishInflate().